# What does poor audience mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Here is the statement..

> We did a show at the party and hardly anyone came. 
>   Great show great place but poor audience.

What does poor audience mean here?
Thaks.

Answer (score -2):

The phrase *poor audience* on its own can mean a few things: an unresponsive audience, a small audience, or (if taken literally) an audience of people without much money.

In this case, the meaning is made clear from the first sentence:

> We did a show at the party and **hardly anyone came**. Great show great place but **poor audience**.

So, few people showed up. Depending on the nature of the show and how it was funded, that can either be just disappointing or it could result in less money being made.

Comment: You’re a vet around here, as much as I am. Questions whose answers would be “immediately obvious to a native speaker with no particular training” should be migrated to ELL for the sake of both the OP and the health of ELU and ELL. They should not be answered here.

Comment: @DanBron This chappie makes his own rules.